# Github error: src refspec main does not match any

Tags: git, github

I tried to follow instructions to do a commit to github, but it broke immediately

```
D:\Work\htdocs\temp>git add *
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .htaccess.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory\

D:\Work\htdocs\temp>git commit -m "first commit"
[master 2f28669] first commit
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .htaccess

D:\Work\VikasSite\htdocs\temp>git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then I realized by default in Github the `master` branch was renamed `main`, so I tried the same thing again

```
D:\Work\htdocs\temp>git push origin --delete master
To https://github.com/*******/php_social_network.git
 - [deleted]         master

D:\Work\htdocs\temp>git commit -m "test"
[master *****] test
 2 files changed, 39 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 github
 create mode 100644 github.pub

D:\Work\htdocs\temp>git push --set-upstream origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/******/php_social_network.git'
```

What did I do wrong here and how can I push to the `main` branch instead?

Comment: As `[master 2f28669] first commit` shows, your current (and in this case only) branch name is `master`, not `main`. Rename `master` to `main` as in VonC's answer, and you will have just one branch named `main`. Note that Git itself assigns no significance to branch names, and once you have at least one commit, you can create as many branch names as you like. They don't *mean* anything and they have very little cost of creation (each one takes just a few bytes of disk space).

Comment: One of the keys to getting used to Git is learning that branch names don't really matter (to Git anyway: humans, on the other hand, ascribe a lot of meaning to their branch names!). Instead, in Git, it's the *commit hash IDs* that actually matter. But they're too big and ugly for humans to work with, so we use branch names to have Git remember the hash IDs for us.

Comment: When you deleted the name `master` on GitHub, you deleted *GItHub's* name. But each repository—there are two at this point, yours on your computer (laptop or whatever) and the one over at GitHub, accessible via the GitHub Linux servers—has *its own separate branch names*.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to rename your local branch master as main first:

```
git branch -m master main
git push -u origin main
```

The `git push origin --delete master` did delete the *remote* `origin/master` branch.

Check the current branch with `git status`, and `git branch -avv`.